# How do I ensure reliable async wav playback in dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, soundplayer

I am playing wav files as user prompts in dotnet.  My code works fine on a laptop, but seems to skip sounds on a netbook.  How do I ensure wav playback is consistent on the netbook in dotnet?
Current code that causes occasional playback problems in netbook:

```
using (var player = new SoundPlayer(pSoundPath))
{
  player.Play();
}
```

Same issue when I pre-load the sounds into a dictionary to call by sound name:

```
Dictionary<string, SoundPlayer> playerDict = new Dictionary<string, SoundPlayer>();
playerDict.Add(soundName, new SoundPlayer(soundPath));
playerDict[soundname].LoadAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps giving a dedicated higher-priority thread to the Player may help. Async != parallel. It could be that the async call is contending for processor time with your foreground work.